# KeyChain Set - NoSuchAttribute - Why?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Here's my code:

```
static void SetA(byte[] b)
{
    var result = SecKeyChain.Add(new SecRecord(SecKind.Key) { Generic = "test", ValueData = NSData.FromArray(b) });
    Debug.WriteLine(result);
}
```

`result` is:

> NoSuchAttribute

- Is it because I'm debugging and when I publish it it'll work?
- Is it because I need to add something to info.plist?
- Is it because I need to specify something in the provisioning
  profile?
- Or is it because I'm missing some step in the code?
- ...

This is my first attempt at using KeyChain, so please don't discount (as in "disregard") any simple mistake I may have made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the exact same error. I was following the official samples from here
https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/Keychain.

I debugged it and found out that the Error `NoSuchAttribute` comes from the `Generic` attribute. In the [official Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/item_attribute_keys_and_values?language=objc) the [kSecAttrGeneric](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattrgeneric?language=objc) attribute is listed under "Password Attributes". So I assume the xamarin example is correct because it uses `SecKind.GenericPassword`.

Replace `Generic` by `Label` or something else to identify your keychain record.

To use your code

```
static void SetA(byte[] b)
{
    var result = SecKeyChain.Add(new SecRecord(SecKind.Key) { 
        Label = "test", 
        ValueData = NSData.FromArray(b) 
    });
    Debug.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because I'm debugging and when I publish it it'll work?

No , Keychain works in debug/release mode.

> Is it because I need to add something to info.plist?

No need.

> Is it because I need to specify something in the provisioning profile?

No need

> Or is it because I'm missing some step in the code?

You need set [keychain-access-groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/entitlements?tabs=windows#keychain-sharing)(bundle identifier) in Entitlements.plist , then in the App's iOS Bundle Signing, ensure that the Custom Entitlements is set to Entitlements.plist .

keychain directly depepds on Bundle id , if bundle id remain same then your app can acess keychain , so provisioning profile should map the same bundle id if app needs to acccess keychain.

At last ,check the offical sample for keychain : https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/Keychain.

Comment: I set the entitlements to include the keychain for the id, and have custom entitlements set to it. Still the same error.

Comment: Ignore the result code , try to store and get data on your device to check if it works , here is proper usage : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12646250/8187800